# How can I escape this regex properly in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, regex, cocoa-touch

I have the following regex I would like to escape in Objective-C

```
/\B\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9\.\:\_\-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[\_\.\-\:](?![\.\_\.\-\:]))*[a-z0-9]+)/ig;
```

Not exactly sure how to escape it so it works in Objective-C

Update:

```
NSString* pattern = @"/\\B\\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9\\.\\:\\_\\-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[\\_\\.\\-\\:](?![\\.\\_\\.\\-\\:]))*[a-z0-9]+)/ig;";
NSRegularExpression *usernameRegex = [[[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern
                                                                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                                                                    error:nil];
                                                                        error:nil];
```

Gives me an error about `Parse Issue - Unexpected Identifier`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Backslashes are used as escape characters in C strings. To make a regexp that contains backslashes as regex escapes, you need to double them.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from the correct solution by millimoose, here is a NSString category method I use to escape black slashes for Regex patterns in Objective C.

```
+ (NSString *)escapeBackslashes:(NSString *)regexString
{
    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\\\" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive | NSRegularExpressionDotMatchesLineSeparators | NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines | NSRegularExpressionAllowCommentsAndWhitespace error:&error];
    if (error == NULL)
    {
        return [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:regexString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [regexString length]) withTemplate:@"\\\\"];
    }
    else
    {
        return regexString;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
NSString* pattern = [NSString escapeBackslashes:pattern];
```